# How can I sort files in Nautilus by modified date?

Tags: 12.04, nautilus

I want to sort files in Nautilus by modified date, similar to sorting files by modified date in Windows Explorer.

How can I sort files in Nautilus by modified date?

Answer (score 3):

It is simple. From the `Menu Bar`, click **View -> Arrange Items -> By Modification Date** :)

Alternatively, depending on the view of your File Manager, you can simply do one of these:

### From Icon/Compact View

[image]

Right-click on an unoccupied area of your File Manager, select **Arrange Items -> By Modification Date**

### From List View

[image]

Simply click **Date Modified** in the bar on top of file list.

To choose between ascending and descending, you can click on the **Date Modified** in the bar once again, or use **Arrange Items -> Reversed Order** from View menu or right-click menu.

Comment: My questions is edit wrongly. I want agreggate archives for modification date. For example.. downloads of today -> here | downloads of past days -> here