# How to make default view in Nautilus arrange file by modify date the most recent at the top

Tags: 16.04, nautilus

I set default view by access date but files always arrange by oldest file  open on top not the most recent file that I open that require me to always click again the *modified column* to make it rearrange to top the most recent

Screen-shot of arrangement by date access:

[image]

Comment: I am having the same default sorting issue, but with ubuntu 22.10. Unfortunately, in this version, it seems like there is no "views" tab in the preferences menu (see image). Does anyone have a solution for the newer version that I am running on? [What I see when I open "Preferences"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Y3l2.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Choose *Edit -> Preferences* and set your preferred layout:

[image]

### Update

**If the First one didn't work(that worked for me) you can try the second-one.**

There's an additional parameter `default-sort-in-reverse-order` that doesn't appear to be accessible from the in-application preferences menu, but can be set in the dconf database.

There is a GUI dconf-editor that allows you to modify such hidden settings - it's not installed by default but available by installing the dconf-tools package. Alternatively you can set it from the command line using gsettings

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences default-sort-in-reverse-order true
```

If the dconf-tools package is installed, there is an equivalent dconf command line

```
$ dconf write /org/gnome/nautilus/preferences/default-sort-in-reverse-order
```

You can revert the change any time with

```
$ gsettings reset org.gnome.nautilus.preferences default-sort-in-reverse-order
```

or

```
$ dconf reset /org/gnome/nautilus/preferences/default-sort-in-reverse-order
```

Note that it applies to whatever the default sort order is, so for example if you change back to sort-by-name that will be reversed as well - there doesn't seem to be a way to specify the sort direction individually.

[Credits](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360248/how-can-i-set-view-preferences-to-sorted-by-reverse-date-modified)

Comment: That is exactly what i set in my preference but the oldest file goes always on top. What i need the most recent on top. Anyway tnx bro

Comment: @ArthurKiskisol I edited my answer hope this one helps you

Comment: $ gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences default-sort-in-reverse-order true     works fine. Thanks hizqeel