# Can't set list view as default in Files

Tags: gnome, nautilus

I just did a fresh install of 16.04.1 and am running gnome flashback Metacity.

I can't seem to find tools to set the default behavior of new windows. I am well aware of how it was done in 12.04 and 14.04 LTS. This link shows it, so clear (flashback, Metacity).

[how to make default view in nautilus arrange file by modify date the most recent at the top](https://askubuntu.com/questions/788493/how-to-make-default-view-in-nautilus-arrange-file-by-modify-date-the-most-recent/788498)

But I don't get these menus with 16.04, seems they should be there. Any help would be appreciated.

Added info:
I logged off Flashback-Metacity and logged on with Unity desktop. I was able to set the default view to "list" with the Edit-Preferences menu that pops up in the top bar. When I log back into flashback-Metacity again that setting still holds and I now get my preferred list view.

But, I Still couldn't find any way to set preferences in a Files window with Metacity; the rightmost icon on the window looks like a Properties offering but that doesn't do it. And with Metacity there is no pop-up menu in the top bar (like Unity) since that is used differently, and no pop-up in the window bar.

Still hoping for some help.

Added: Screenshot was requested, added. I haven't found any other non-techy way to set properties, but the terminal mode method is appreciated until a fix. Thanks.

Added: The terminal mode commands suggested by Awar do fix the problem, but that does not fix the deficiencies of the behavior of the new Ubuntu 16.04 with Gnome Metacity; the missing items in the "Location Options" menu. I now wish I had not upgraded.

There are other problems also: I can't imagine these changes are intentional and I report this trying to make the product better and more user-friendly and functional. If you go to the "Location Options"  pulldown and select "New Folder" it does not create a new folder in the current window UNTIL you click in the window; it formerly did this instantly. ALSO, if you go to "Location Options"  pull-down (with a folder or file selected) and select Properties, there is a long delay (several seconds) then a transparent and empty window box appears and only when you click in the window does it finally show the item properties window. IF, with an item selected in the window, you Rt-click and select Properties, it immediately shows the Properties window.  And this, my last complaint, is just something I see as a necessary tool that seems to be lost now: In 14.04LTS/Metacity you could Rt-Click in a folder window and get New Document and New Folder choices : these are wicked useful that I used a thousand times a day, and these Rt-click actions are no longer available. These are all changes, deficiencies, issues with the handling of the "Location Options" pull-down menu and I think it is a a problem in the code and not an intentional "feature change".

[image: This is the Gnome-Metacity Nautilus file menu. In 14.04LTS there was "Preferences" on this menu.]

Comment: I had similar issues with gnome flashback Metacity and was unable to resolve them. Someone suggested I try Ubuntu MATE which I did and have stayed with it abandoning gnome flashback Metacity.

Comment: Quite right it seems. I recently updated 14.04LTS to 16.04LTS and I can't set list view of files either. Might it just be an 'undocumented software event' aka bug worthy of reporting?

Comment: post a screenshot of your nautilus where the menu is missing

Comment: Have you checked the answer given? Did that answer your question?

Comment: The terminal mode commands do fix the problem, but that does not fix the deficiencies of the behavior of the new Ubuntu 16.04 with Gnome Metacity; the missing items in the settings menu. I wish I had not upgraded. There are other problems also:

Answer (score 3):

I too have this problem. After searching here and there and trying several hacking, I found that this actually is a bug. The bug has been reported to both Gnome mailing list and launchpad. Here is the two links of the bug.

- [Gnome Mailing List](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gnome-flashback-list/2016-March/msg00004.html)
- [Bug #1565780](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1565780) on Launchpad
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1274740 (related)

In the meantime, I found that I had a package `gtk3-nocsd` from webupd8. After removing that package (`sudo apt-get remove gtk3-nocsd`) I could at least enabled the Menu Button for Preference, but clicking it doesn't work.

### Until the bug is fixed, you can control Nautilus preference this terminal way:

- Set default folder view to **List View**

  ```
    gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences default-folder-viewer 'list-view'
  ```
- Set default folder view to **Icon View**

  ```
    gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences default-folder-viewer 'icon-view'
  ```
- Sort by **Name**

  ```
    gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences default-sort-order 'name'
  ```
- Sort by **File Size**

  ```
    gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences default-sort-order 'size'
  ```
- Sort by **Type**

  ```
     gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences default-sort-order 'type'
  ```
- Sort by **File Modification Time**

  ```
     gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences default-sort-order 'mtime'
  ```
- Sort by **File Accessed Time**

  ```
     gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences default-sort-order 'atime'
  ```
- Open with **Single Click**

  ```
    gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences click-policy 'single'
  ```
- Open with **Double Click**

  ```
    gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences click-policy 'double'
  ```

Comment: You can write a bash script with all these setting commands and include it in Startup Applications in order to avoid doing it every time you login.